# Resize html before exporting to pdf with jspdf .html() method

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to figure out how to resize a HTML element with jsPDF [`.html()`](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html) method.

I tried with the code below but the `width` option does not seem to make any change in the output.

I am just assuming `width` is an option of `.html()` as unfortunately, as of now, 
there's no documentation to this method and one is supposed to guess it [from the code](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/modules_html.js.html#line749).

Also, it seems to me it should takes the option from the [html2canvas options](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration/), that's why I tried with `width`.

Anyway, the code:

```
var legend = document.getElementById("my-table");
var pdf = new jsPDF(orientation, undefined, format);
pdf.html(legend, {
    width: 200,
    callback: function () {
        window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'));
     }
});
```

**#my-table**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="image1.jpeg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="image2.jpeg"></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passing options to html2canvas:

```
pdf.html(legend, {
    html2canvas: {
        // insert html2canvas options here, e.g.
        width: 200
    },
    callback: function () {
        // ...
    }
});
```

For me, the option `scale` works fine for resizing. You can retrieve the default page dimensions [listed in the source](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/modules_html.js.html#line670) to calculate the required scaling factor.

Comment: Thanks. Tried with scale:0.5 and worked fine. Accepted.

Comment: What is the `image` option?

Comment: This worked for me.
`html2canvas(element, {`
`scale: 1,`
`}).then((canvas) => { `
`...`
`}`

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find a way to resize HTML objects. Instead, you can change the measurement unit from mm (default) to pt. This will reduce all sizes to about 1/3 from the original. For example:

```
doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4');
```

IMPORTANT: any other objects (i.e. text, lines, etc) will reduce too, in size and position. So be careful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly about jspdf is, but it seems you've miss spelled on

```
var legend = document.getElementsById("my-table");
```

here.

```
var legend = document.getElementById("my-table");
```

and maybe, you could resize those tables via css or style attribute.

```
<table style="width:200;">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="image1.jpeg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="image2.jpeg"></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

using css

```
#my-table {
 width:200;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will change the mispelled code. Anyway, the problem is I don't want to resize the table via css because as long as jsPDF converts it to PDF, it will however try to fit to the page size.

Comment: @umbe1987 okay, or you could fixing width and height of your document, and layout all stuff. just theory though... and I found html documentation. check here  https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html

Comment: Thanks again. I know that page of the documentation, but if you look at it, there's no desription for the options except "An object of optional settings."